# Play can only support up to 100 open connections

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I uses Play 2.5.x and Netty. I have configured the Linux server to support 65535 open connections.

However, play crashes everytime when the open connections reach 100. Is there anything else i should configure?

```
netstat -n | awk '/^tcp/ {++state[$NF]} END {for(key in state) print key,"/t",state[key]}'
CLOSE_WAIT /t 1
ESTABLISHED /t 100
TIME_WAIT /t 273


play {
akka {
akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
loglevel = WARNING
actor {
  default-dispatcher = {
    fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-factor = 3.0
        parallelism-min = 8
        parallelism-max = 64
        task-peeking-mode = "FIFO"
    }
  }
}
 }
 }
```

Comment: Define "crashes" ? Do you get a stacktrace ? Anything in the kernel log ? I've run play with > 10k connections, so this should not be an issue.

Comment: @Igmar Palsenberg crashes means play stopped working. I dont see any error in the logs.can you check if fork-join-executor is defined correctly?